# Find least Rate in a List<T> in a specific group

Tags: c#, linq

I have  List<Rates> finalReportDetails and it contains multiple rates for same WebsiteId and CheckInDate.
I need to have only one record for each websiteId and checkindate.
This record either should have the lowest Rate (1st preference) or with Rate -1.
Rest all records for this group should be removed from the list.

Initial List

```
 List<Rates> rates = new List<Rates>()
    {
        new Rates { CheckInDate = timeValue, websiteId = 1, price = 1 },
        new Rates { CheckInDate = timeValue, websiteId = 1, price = 2 },
        new Rates { CheckInDate = timeValue, websiteId = 2, price = -1 },
        new Rates { CheckInDate = timeValue, websiteId = 2, price = 2 },
        new Rates { CheckInDate = timeValue, websiteId = 3, price = -1 },
        new Rates { CheckInDate = timeValue, websiteId = 3, price = -1 },
    };
```

Final List

```
List<Rates> rates = new List<Rates>()
        {
            new Rates { CheckInDate = timeValue, websiteId = 1, price = 1 },
            new Rates { CheckInDate = timeValue, websiteId = 2, price = 2 },
            new Rates { CheckInDate = timeValue, websiteId = 3, price = -1 },
        };
```

I have tried this code, but going through the loop takes a lot of time.
First I have found distinct groups by by CheckInDate, WebsiteId.
Then for each group, I am checking for the required rate.

```
    class Rates {
    public int websiteId {get; set;},
    public DateTime CheckInDate {get; set;}
    public decimal price {get; set;}}


var grouped = (from s in finalReportDetails
                           select new { s.CheckInDate,s.websiteId  })
                           .Distinct()
                           .ToList();

for (int i = 1; i <= grouped.Count && finalReportDetails.Count != grouped.Count; i++)
{
    var obj = grouped[i - 1];

    // Fetch records for one group, order by rate to find the least Rate
    var grpFinalReportDetails = (from s in Rates
                                 where && s.CheckInDate == obj.CheckInDate && s.websiteId == obj.websiteId
                                 select s).OrderBy(x => x.price).ToList();

    // Deletion necessary only if there is more than one rate for same parameters
    if (grpFinalReportDetails.Count > 1)
    {
        // Tracks if a valid rate is found
        bool isFound = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < grpFinalReportDetails.Count; j++)
        {
            // Checks if a valid least rate is found
            if (!isFound && grpFinalReportDetails[j].InitialRates.Rates > 0)
            {
                isFound = true;
                continue;
            }

            // Delete all but one records whose Rate is less than 0  OR whose rate is more than the cheapest rate
            if ((grpFinalReportDetails[j].InitialRates.Rates <= 0 && j < grpFinalReportDetails.Count - 1) || isFound)
            {
                finalReportDetails.Remove(grpFinalReportDetails[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any faster way to find the same using linq?
Or something that can be optmized in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this LINQ query might do what you want - at least, it passes your example:

```
var result = rates
    .GroupBy(rate => rate.websiteId)
    .Select(@group => 
        @group.Any(rate => rate.price > 0)
            ? @group.Where(rate => rate.price > 0).OrderBy(rate => rate.price).First()
            : @group.OrderBy(rate => rate.price).First())
```

(The `@` sign in the variable name `@group` is because `group` is a reserved word. If you choose a different variable name, you don't need `@`.)

Note that this might iterate over your enumerable several times, so if this is a list coming from some expensive operation (like a database query), be sure to call `.ToList()` first, to avoid invoking the expensive operation more than once.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Some initializing code for testing
var timeValue = DateTime.Now;
List<Rates> rates = new List<Rates>()
{
    new Rates { CheckInDate = timeValue, websiteId = 1, price = 1 },
    new Rates { CheckInDate = timeValue, websiteId = 1, price = 2 },
    new Rates { CheckInDate = timeValue, websiteId = 2, price = -1 },
    new Rates { CheckInDate = timeValue, websiteId = 2, price = 2 },
    new Rates { CheckInDate = timeValue, websiteId = 3, price = -1 },
    new Rates { CheckInDate = timeValue, websiteId = 3, price = -1 },
};

//The actual relevant code
var result = rates.GroupBy(item => new { item.websiteId, item.CheckInDate })
                  .Select(grp => grp.Any(item => item.price != -1) ?
                      grp.Where(item => item.price != -1).OrderBy(item => item.price).First() :
                      grp.First())
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Why not group.Min(item => item.price)?

Comment: `Min` by `price` will return the lowest price of the group but what I want is the `Rate` that has the lowest `price`.

Comment: There is one issue. I have some Rates with price = -1. I need to select the Rate either the lowest price (>0) (1st preference), if present or Rate with price  -1.

Comment: @GiladGreen I have edited the question. See if the example makes it clear.

Comment: @GunmeetSingh - fixed it :) is it what you need?

Comment: @GunmeetSingh - you had a nice interesting question :) liked it